# CORS error on trying to call controller action method with return type view from another application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, cors, http-post, actionresult

Am trying to trigger the Post method of application-1 and open in new window or tab.

Application-1

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostSearch(object searchInput)
    {
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Studnet")
    }
}
```

want to trigger this post method from application-2.

```
<input type="button" id="search"  
value="Trigger Post"  onclick="TriggerPostSearch('1234')"/> 

 function TriggerPostSearch(searchObject) {
        var url = "http://www.localhost:99/test/PostSearch";
        OpenWindowWithPost(url, searchObject);
    };

  function OpenWindowWithPost(url, model) {
        var param = { "searchInput": model };
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data:param
        }).done(function(result){
        window.open(url, '_blank');
        });
    }
```

Enabled CORS in app-1 to accept request from app-2. Is there any otherway of doing this?

Comment: 1. XMLHttpRequest and HTTP Request both are different. Browser can render a page only with HTTP GET request.
2. XMLHttpRequest could return partial view/json/string etc., but it cannot give a HTML to a browser with 302 status (Permanent Redirection).

Comment: Thanks you, I will try this